# How to change max and min of a SpinnerNumberModel properly with the implemented Setters

Tags: java, swing, comparable, jspinner

I want to implement a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` to a `GUI`. The values for `value, min, max, step` are read from a ini-file **after** the `GUI` gets built, therefore I need to change them with the `Setters` from the `SpinnerNumberModel` class. The values are read from the file as a `String`, then get parsed to `double`.

The `JSpinner` and `SpinnerNumberModel` are implemented in a class `InputSpinner`:

```
public class InputSpinner implements ChangeListener {

    JSpinner component;
    SpinnerNumberModel model;

    //empty constructor
    public InputSpinner() {
        model = new SpinnerNumberModel();   
        component = new JSpinner(model);

        JComponent field = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) component.getEditor());
        Dimension prefSize = field.getPreferredSize();
        prefSize = new Dimension(50, prefSize.height);
        field.setPreferredSize(prefSize);

        component.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    //constructor with name
    public InputSpinner(String name) {
        model = new SpinnerNumberModel();
        component = new JSpinner(model);
        component.setName(name);

        JComponent field = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) component.getEditor());
        Dimension prefSize = field.getPreferredSize();
        prefSize = new Dimension(50, prefSize.height);
        field.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
        component.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    //basic properties for all possible components
    public void setName(String componentName) {
        component.setName(componentName);
    }

    public void setToolTipText(String tooltip) {
        component.setToolTipText(tooltip);
    }

    public void setValue (Number value) {
        model.setValue(value);
    }

    public void setMaximum (Number max) {
        model.setMaximum((Comparable<Double>)max);
    }

    public void setMinimum (Number min) {
        model.setMinimum((Comparable<Double>)min);
    }

    public void setStepSize (Number step) {
        model.setStepSize(step);    
    }

    //getter for item
    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return this.component;
    }
}
```

As the `Setters` for `StepSize` and `Value` have `Number` as transfer parameters, I can set them after instancing both the `SpinnerNumberModel` and the `JSpinner` and it obviosly works that way.

The `Setters` for `min` and `max` otherwise demand the type `Comparable`.
Simply parsing the double values to `Comparable` (raw type) or `Comparable<Double>` does not cause an exception, but also causes the `JSpinner` to not work properly anymore. (The initial value cannot be changed neither by editing nor by using the 2 Buttons that come with the editor).

When I add a `JSpinner` to my GUI and then change the values I do it like this:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    InputSpinner spinner = new InputSpinner("spinner");

    frame.add(spinner.getComponent());

    spinner.setValue(some double value I got from ini-file);    //works properly
    spinner.setStepSize(some double value I got from ini-file); //works properly

    spinner.setMinimum(some double value I got from ini-file);  //causes problems
    spinner.setMaximum(some double value I got from ini-file);  //causes problems

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    return;
}
```

}

How do I set the values properly, respectively how should I deal with the demand for `Comparable` ?

Comment: It seems to me you can just replace Number with `double` in your set-methods.  No need for any casting or conversion;  it will be autoboxed by the compiler in order to satisfy the calls to the SpinnerNumberModel methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know why exactly your set methods don't work with double, but i found a way to use double as current, min , max and stepsize.

if you create you model, you pass the values in constructor like this:

```
double current = 5.7;
double min = (double) 5.5;
double max = (double) 7.3;
double step = 0.1;
model = new SpinnerNumberModel(current, min, max, step);
```

it doesn't matter which values you use, but they seem to be double if you want to use double further, because then this code works as well:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
InputSpinner spinner = new InputSpinner("spinner");

frame.add(spinner.getComponent());

spinner.setValue(5.1); 
spinner.setMinimum(1.0); 
spinner.setMaximum(25.3);  
spinner.setStepSize(2.5);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

as i see it, you have to set step size as last value somewhy, but now its working just fine

Comment: You are right, the trick was to use the the Constructor for model that already has 4 double values as transfer params (I used some random values as I set them to another value then anyway) AND to set step as last value. Then it works!

Please edit the second code fragment of yours, the Setters you use are implemented in `SpinnerNumberModel`, not in `JSpinner`! (it needs to be `model.set....`